# Why is my JWT token not allowing me to access an authorized endpoint in .NET Core WEB API 6?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, authorization

I can login and generate a token successfully, but when I make a request to an endpoint that requires authorization and pass in my token, I still get a 401 response in Postman.

Here is my Program code:

```
global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Token"]))
    };
    
});


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And here is where I generate the token.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login([FromBody] UserDto request)
        {
            var userToLogin = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.username == request.username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if(userToLogin == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("User not found.");
            }

            if(userToLogin.username != request.username)
            {
                return BadRequest("Wrong username.");
            }

            if (!verifyPasswordHash(request.password, userToLogin.password))
            {
                return BadRequest("Wrong password");
            }
            string token = createToken(request.username);
            return Ok(token);
        }

        private string createToken(string username)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(claims: claims, signingCredentials: creds, expires: DateTime.MaxValue);

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }
```

And here's my appsettings.json file:

```
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost\\sqlexpress;database=poetrydb;trusted_connection=true"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "Token": "sakdkvsksjwasjaiao3949cksqoqo39c9dj4e",
    "Issuer": "JWTAuthenticationServer",
    "Audience":  "JWTServicePostmanClient"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you add the token in postman, can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Sure thing. I go to the authorization tab and add the token as a Bearer token. Here's the screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/nn6Z2l7.png

Comment: sorry cannot help, looks good to me... the only thing that makes me unsecure is that you read the value of AppSettings:Token (GetSection vs Configuration[]) diffrent when createing token from validating -  but I guess you get the same string-value?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem. I was not passing in the token secret to the .AddJwtBearer method. After passing it in, my program works as expected.

Comment: can you show how you did that because i have the same struggle?!